# Confidence Interval of AUC ROC more than 1?

Tags: confidence-interval, auc

I'm analyzing a biomarker, and the Sens and Spec look promising (>90). however, the AUROC confidence interval is (0.929 to 1.016).  I have a small sample size, however I would like to know how to interpret the confidence interval, does it mean that it is not significant?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to CV! How did you obtain this confidence interval? It seems incorrect that it could result in an area under the curve greater than 1.

Comment: There are two issues here. 1) How to interpret the confidence interval exceeding 1 when you know the AUC is capped at 1. 2) How to use the confidence interval to make some kind of inference. Addressing the second, when you say “significant”, what do you mean? What is your null hypothesis, and what is your alternative hypothesis?

Comment: Hi thank you for taking the time of answering this. I was more interested in how to interpret the confidence interval exceeding 1.

Answer (score 1):

First: You don't say what software or method you used to get those CI for AUC. But, either you chose the wrong options or it's a bad method (or, less likely, bad software). Maybe it was a naive implementation of the standard CI of 
$$ 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}$$
but this doesn't work well when p is close to 0 or 1, nor is it specific to AUC.

The ci.auc function in R uses (by default) bootstrap estimation.

Second: as Dave noted in a comment, "significant" needs to be defined here. Certainly the AUC is signficantly different from 0 - but that's hardly a useful test. It's also significantly different from 0.5 (which is what you would expect if the classifier was useless). That's a little more useful. But if you want a p-value (I'm not sure that you should want one, but if you do) you need to state a null hypothesis.